# Purchases.Voidedpurchases.List returns empty response

Tags: c#, google-api, google-play, google-api-dotnet-client, in-app

I'm making request to [google Android Publisher api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher) to check purchases that has been voided in my application. The problem is that response is always empty (with code 200). I have some refunded purchases from within 30 days. I tried to make this request using C# android publisher nuget package and manually using postman. The result is successful but empty.

```
        string           contents   = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("D:/Projects/android-publisher-api-key.json");
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(contents);

        string[] scopes = { AndroidPublisherService.Scope.Androidpublisher };

        credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName       = "Test App"
        };

        AndroidPublisherService androidPublisherService = new AndroidPublisherService(initializer);

        var request  = androidPublisherService.Purchases.Voidedpurchases.List("com.MyCompany.MyTestApp");
        var response = await request.ExecuteAsync(); // In this response all fields are null
```

Using postman I send request to (with bearerToken):
`https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.MyCompany.MyTestApp/purchases/voidedpurchases`

Response is success 200 but body contains only `{}`. It should at least have the structure listed in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/voided-purchases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. If you encountered problem like this and you are refunding purchases via google play console then in refund form you must check the `Remove entitlement` checkbox. Otherwise the voided purchase will not be included as response.