# How long does take for refunded purchase to become visible in the voidedpurchases.list?

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

Coming from [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#8) I'm trying to implement a check on my server, that will fetch voided purchases and remove them from database. But for some reason the most recent voided purchase returned by the following code is dated 19.06.2023, but there are refunded purchases yesterday and today (21.06.2023).

```dart
    final voidedPurchases = await androidPublisher.purchases.voidedpurchases.list(
      androidPackageId,
      type: 0,
      maxResults: 1000,
    );
```

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67007114) post and all refund were done with **Remove entitlement** enabled.